# How do I find out the version of the current Trigger.io Forge platform?

Tags: trigger.io, forge

I want to lock down the Forge platform version that I build my app on. I believe I can do this by updating the value for `platform_version` in the config.json file.

But how do I find out the current platform version from the command line? I want to use the commandline because the website (http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.3/release-notes.html) not fully up to date because of the quick releases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - there are two options:

- look at https://trigger.io/forge/platform_version/ to see available major/minor versions
- look at `.template/platform_version.txt` in your app directory which contains the minor version used to create a particular build

See http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.3/release-notes.html#v1-3-12

Comment: Yeah that would be good, as long as we know which working version to lock the app down to.

Comment: can you update your answer with the changes in the v1.3.12 build so I can mark this as complete?